# Jquery nested datatable second child not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my project I have used jquery nested datatable,I have 2childs row for each row in datatble, below is my code

```
$(function(){$(document).on('click','#tab td.control', function(){
      var nTr = this.parentNode;
      var oData = $('#tab').dataTable().fnGetData(nTr);
      console.log(oData);
       .....etc.....
});
```

If I click parent td means the 2 child rows open, and this.parentNode shows the parent node details based on that details , I will shows additional details about parent node,below code for child row,

```
$(function(){$(document).on('click','table[id^="inner_param_"] td.control', function(){
    var nTrs = this.parentNode;
     var ooDatas = we.fnGetData(nTrs);
     console.log(ooDatas);
           .....etc.....
});
```

If I click parent node first child means that child open and console shows parent node details, but second child not working and console shows null for parent node details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got solution,
Just change `#tab td.control` to `#tab > tbody > tr > td.control`